# Error Code 400: Invalid Value - Google Play IAP Verification Failure

Tags: php, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, verification

I had working code in my server, that verified in-app purchases.

There are already 2 days, that my verification started give me a bad response.

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalid",
                "message": "Invalid Value"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid Value"
    }
}
```

Nothing changed on my side.

(P.S. I'm able to get an access token via refresh, so, I assume I have no problems with my credentials).

Here is the code, that worked OK before.

```
$product_sku = $_REQUEST['product_sku'];
$transaction_id = $_REQUEST['transaction_id'];
$transaction_time = $_REQUEST['transaction_time'];
$purchase_data = @$_REQUEST['purchase_data'];
$market = $_REQUEST['market'];

$verified = false;
$test_purchase = false;
if (isset($product_sku) && isset($transaction_id) && isset($transaction_time) && isset($market)) {

    // If it's GOOGLE
    if ($market == '2') {

        // verifies if the IAB is correct
        if (isset($purchase_data) && $purchase_data != "") {

            // Getting necessary data for verification
            $client_id = file_get_contents('google_play_developer_api_client_id');
            $client_secret = file_get_contents('google_play_developer_api_client_secret');
            $refresh_token = file_get_contents('google_play_developer_api_refresh_token');
            $refresh_token_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
            $verification_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/mypackage/purchases/products/" . $product_sku . "/tokens/" . $purchase_data;

            // Preparing for the REFRESH_TOKEN request. This need to be changed after Memcache enabling.
            // Will be needed to store the ACCESS_TOKEN in the Memcache for the expiration time and after expiring get new ACCESS_TOKEN with REFRESH_TOKEN

            // constructing the necessary data for Google authentication
            $data_array = array(
                "grant_type" => "refresh_token",
                "client_id" => $client_id,
                "client_secret" => $client_secret,
                "refresh_token" => $refresh_token
            );

            // replacing '\/' with '/' as after json_encode() the '/' in the array values will be replaced with '\/'
            $data_array = str_replace("\/", "/", json_encode($data_array));

            // contracting Headers for the REFRESH_TOKEN request
            $headers = array(
                'APIKEY: 111111111111111111111',
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );

            // making REFRESH_TOKEN request and getting the new ACCESS_TOKEN
            $make_call = callAPI('POST', $refresh_token_url, $data_array, $headers);

            $response = json_decode($make_call, true);

            if (array_key_exists("access_token", $response)) {
                $accessToken = $response["access_token"];

                // preparing for the Verification request

                // adding necessary headers
                array_push($headers, "Authorization: OAuth " . $accessToken, "Accept: application/json");

                // making Verification request and getting the receipt from Google
                $make_call = callAPI('GET', $verification_url, false, $headers);
                $receipt = json_decode($make_call, true);

                if (array_key_exists("purchaseState", $receipt)) {
                    // checking for the test purchase or for the purchase made using promo code.
                    // if purchaseType exists in the receipt the it is test purchase or the purchase made using promo code
                    // purchaseType = 0 -> Test Purchase, purchaseType = 1 -> Purchase made using promo code
                    if (array_key_exists("purchaseType", $receipt)) {
                        $purchaseType = $receipt["purchaseType"];
                        $test_purchase = $purchaseType == 0;
                    }

                    // Getting the purchaseState from the receipt.
                    // purchaseState = 0 -> Successfull purchase, purchaseState = 0 -> Canceled purchase
                    $purchaseState = $receipt["purchaseState"];

                    // Getting Order Id from the receipt
                    $order_id = $receipt["orderId"];

                    // Getting Purchase Time from the receipt. Time in millis from the Unix Epoch
                    $purchaseTimeMillis = $receipt["purchaseTimeMillis"];

                    // Verifying the purchase
                    // Verification is failed for any of the following reasons
                    // 1. Test purchase or the purchase made using promo code
                    // 2. Canceled Purchase
                    // 3. If the order id from receipt and the transaction id from the mobile app are different
                    // 4. If the PurchaseTime from the receipt and the Transaction Time from the mobile are different
                    // If all conditions are true, the purchase is verified.

                    $verified = ($purchaseState == 0 && $order_id == $transaction_id && $purchaseTimeMillis == $transaction_time);

                } elseif(!array_key_exists("error", $receipt)){
                        // Something went wrong, let's set the verified to true, so we don't know if it is cheating

                        $verified = true;
                }
            } else {
                // Something went wrong, let's set the verified to true, so we don't know if it is cheat
                $verified = true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Changed this, while adding verification for other platforms
        $verified = true;
    }

    $verified = $verified ? 1 : 0;
    $test_purchase = $test_purchase ? 1 : 0;
    // Updating verified and test Purchase fields in the payment_transaction table
    // The default value is 1, so no need for updating , if the payment is verified
    if ($verified == 0 || $test_purchase == 1) {
        dbQuery("UPDATE payment_transaction SET verified=$verified, test_purchase=$test_purchase WHERE user_id=$user_id AND txnid='$transaction_id'", $user_id);
    }
    $output['status'] = 'ok';
    $output['verified'] = $verified;
    $output['test_purchase'] = $test_purchase;
}

echo json_encode($output);

function callAPI($method, $url, $data = false, $headers = null)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method) {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "GET":
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    // OPTIONS:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    if ($headers) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

    // EXECUTE:
    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    if (! $result) {
        die("Connection Failure");
    }
    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}

?>
```

Any Ideas what may be the reason for the bad response? 
I have tried to generate a new refresh token, but the result is the same. (

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Hi @Dharman. Yes, you are right and I know that and I'll change that in the near future. This bad practice was done before me, and I just continue to make this way anything until I'll change all this code made by 'bad practice'.

BUT now, my question is another. Will you be able to help me?

Comment: p.s. @Dharman. There are no any queries in this example )

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the problem. The PurchaseToken was incorrect in my case.

BTW, the Error Code 400 means that the authentication is ok , but some data is invalid. In my case, it was the PurchaseToken.

Comment: Can you explain what was wrong with the token? I got the same error and suspected the token, but I could not reproduce by simply changing some char in the token (it gave me a different error)

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry , I can't remember what exactly was wrong with my PurchaseToken.

Comment: Can we verify the test payment?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely some values you provided for payment validation is not as expected. In my case, I missed a field in my data. If it's a subscription, you will need to add:

```
{ subscription: true, 
... //(other data) 
}
```

For play store validation, as far as I know you need the following fields:

```
productId, purchaseToken, packageName.
```

Don't miss spell the filed names including case.